# Vuetify text doesn't display over carousel image

Tags: image, vue.js, text, carousel, vuetify.js

I am using VueJS and Vuetify and when next image 
in carousel shows the text only blinks there and goes away.

I want the text to be displayed with the image
and I don't want it to create unnecessary slides because of two loops.

My code:

```
<template>
  <v-carousel hide-delimiters height="750" show-arrows-on-hover cycle>
    <v-carousel-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" :src="item.src">
      <v-carousel-item v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :key="i">
        <v-row class="fill-height" align="center" justify="center">
          <div class="display-3 white--text">{{ slide }}</div>
        </v-row>
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</template>
```

My script:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "homeCarousel",

  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          src: "https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/d5/wallhaven-d518dj.jpg"
        },
        {
          src: "https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/j8/wallhaven-j82el5.png"
        },
        {
          src: "https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/yj/wallhaven-yj1qk7.png"
        }
      ],
      slides: ["Innovation", "Design", "Technology"]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: you probably shouldn't nest a `v-carousel-item` inside of another `v-carosel-item` much less use `i` as an index for both

Comment: what is in `slides`? and is it the same length as `items`?

Comment: @depperm In slides its just text to be displayed over the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one `v-carousel-item` and for `slides` reference `slides[i]`

```
<template>
  <v-carousel hide-delimiters height="750" show-arrows-on-hover cycle>
    <v-carousel-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" :src="item.src">
      <v-row class="fill-height" align="center" justify="center">
        <div class="display-3 white--text">{{ slides[i] }}</div>
      </v-row>
    </v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</template>
```